# Change datagrid cell button method and content after click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, datagrid

i got answer. I'm writing SignalR app and want to change dataGrid cell button after click. Everything seems ok, when i clicked it changed, but when i try to set event for button its not working. Can you recommend any way to do this?

XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="chatRoomsGridView"  Margin="0,41,10,0">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room name" Binding="{Binding Path='RoomName'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Users in room" Binding="{Binding Path='UsersAmount'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Connect">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="connectionButton" Click="joinToRoomButton_Click">                                    
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Connect"></Setter>                                                 
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Disconnect"></Setter>
                                                </Trigger>                                                 
                                            </Style.Triggers>                                            
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>                                    
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I tried to set cheked and uncheked event for button with different events but this is not working. Only one of this event working and if you try to put both events, only one trigggers and restore button to checked state. Can you advise me better way to do this?

I tried this method, but not working, because button instantly back to default satet after click. So it cant just get another event and content

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Connect">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="connectionButton" Unchecked="joinToRoomButton_Click" Checked="joinToRoomButton_Click">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Connect"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Content" Value="Disconnect"></Setter>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Join to room event:

```
 private async void joinToRoomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Room name from DataGridView
            Room selectedRoom = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Room;
            CurrentRoom = selectedRoom.RoomName;

            string message = $"{Username} connected to {CurrentRoom} room";

            await connection.InvokeAsync("JoinChatRoom", CurrentRoom);
            await connection.InvokeAsync("ConnectedToGroup", message, CurrentRoom);                

            chatListBox.Items.Add($"You connected to {CurrentRoom} room");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            chatListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
        }            
    }
```

Left from room event:

```
  private async void leftFromRoomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Room selectedRoom = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Room;
            CurrentRoom = selectedRoom.RoomName;

            string message = $"{Username} is disconnected from {CurrentRoom} room";

            await connection.InvokeAsync("LeaveChatRoom", CurrentRoom);
            await connection.InvokeAsync("ConnectedToGroup", message, CurrentRoom);

            chatListBox.Items.Add($"You disconnected from {CurrentRoom} room");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            chatListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: A better way to do what exactly?

Comment: @mm8 To change toggle button method and content. Or better template for this. Maybe justa regular button with specific methods. I'm not pro at wpf so that's why asking

Comment: Why do you need a `Click` event handler? What is it currently doing?

Comment: I dont exectly need Click event. I need something which can be changed after click. So i just try to set new event on Click method after execution and in other method set it back.

Comment: But it's unclear what you have tried since you haven't posted any code...

Comment: @mm8 Btw on click event handler is joinToRoom event, which connect user to chat room

Comment: Do you want to change the `Content` on the `ToggleButton` based on its own `IsChecked` property or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 So i want to make button. Default state "joinToRoom" event and "Conenct" content. After click its doing some job and than change event to "leftFroomRoon" and "Disconnect" content. After clicking on "Disconnect", restore it back to default state. Thats what im trying to do. I not sure that toggle button is the best way to do this

Comment: What do you mean by "change event"? Can't you just handle the `Unchecked` and `Checked` events?

Comment: @mm8 Thats is the problem. When this both handlers on button at the same time, only one working. For some reason button permanently changed state to "Checked/Unchecked"(demands which is default)

Comment: @mm8 Sorry about that, already posted

Comment: When you check the button you want to join the chat, right? And when you uncheck if you want to leave?

Comment: @mm8 Absolutely right

Comment: Then you could change the `Content` property in the event handlers. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events programmatically, you could just set the `Content` property to the initial value in the template in the XAML markup and then change it in the event handlers:

```
private async void joinToRoomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton)sender;

        //Room name from DataGridView
        Room selectedRoom = toggleButton.DataContext as Room;
        CurrentRoom = selectedRoom.RoomName;

        string message = $"{Username} connected to {CurrentRoom} room";

        await connection.InvokeAsync("JoinChatRoom", CurrentRoom);
        await connection.InvokeAsync("ConnectedToGroup", message, CurrentRoom);

        chatListBox.Items.Add($"You connected to {CurrentRoom} room");

        toggleButton.Content = "Disconnect";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        chatListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async void leftFromRoomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton)sender;

        Room selectedRoom = toggleButton.DataContext as Room;
        CurrentRoom = selectedRoom.RoomName;

        string message = $"{Username} is disconnected from {CurrentRoom} room";

        await connection.InvokeAsync("LeaveChatRoom", CurrentRoom);
        await connection.InvokeAsync("ConnectedToGroup", message, CurrentRoom);

        chatListBox.Items.Add($"You disconnected from {CurrentRoom} room");

        toggleButton.Content = "Connect";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        chatListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="connectionButton" Content="Connect" 
                  Checked="joinToRoomButton_Click"
                  Unchecked="leftFromRoomButton_Click" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Still withoud any changes. Only connect event gets triggered and content doesnt changes

Comment: Are you getting an exception then? Remove the `try/catch` clause.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your code to find out what actually happens? Of course the event handler will get invoked if you click on the right button...

Comment: Removing try catch block doesn’t give any results. I pressed correct button. And I I try with breakpoint, my join event told that content was changed but nothing happened inside gridview. Something like that

Comment: Maybe checked and unchecked it’s not a good choice for my situation or maybe I just doing something wrong?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Does the `toggleButton.Content` line of code execute? If so, you are looking at the wrong `ToggleButton`. Maybe you have more than once instance of the view/window open?